# Why doesn't this simple composition work?

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

I was recently in need of putting `head` in between two monadic operations. Here's the SSCCE:

```
module Main where

f :: IO [Int]
f = return [1..5]

g :: Int -> IO ()
g = print

main = do
    putStrLn "g <$> head <$> f"
    g <$> head <$> f

    putStrLn "g . head <$> f"
    g . head <$> f

    putStrLn "head <$> f >>= g"
    head <$> f >>= g
```

This program is well-formed and compiles without warnings. However, only one version out of 3 above works<sup>1</sup>. Why is that?

And specifically, what would be the best way to link `f` and `g` together with `head` in the middle? I ended up using the 3rd one (in the form of `do` notation), but I don't really like it, since it should be a trivial one-liner<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Spoiler alert: the 3rd one is the only one that prints `1`; the other two are silent, both under `runhaskell` and `repl`.

<sup>2</sup> I do realize that those are all one-liners, but the order of operations feels really confusing in the only one that works.

Comment: `(<$>)` is left associative, so that means that `g <$> head <$> f`, is `(g <$> head) <$> f`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sure, but `g <$> (head <$> f)` doesn't work either. And frankly, I'm a bit puzzled as to why *any* of the above wouldn't work.

Comment: Well in the above you `fmap` the values, so `g <$> head <$> f` basically creates an `IO (IO [Int]))`, not an `IO ()`.

Comment: Ah, I laughed when I read that. So obvious, yet so tricky! Put that in an answer so I can accept it :) I really wonder if it could be possible to at least emit a warning for that; after all it's an unintentionally discarded value.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i think the type is `IO (IO ())`.

Comment: @JonasDuregård: yes, that was a typo (but the five minutes were already passed before I noticed it). In the answer I argue that it is `IO (IO ())` :)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz if you want an error for mistakes like these you can write it as a binding: `() <- g . head <$> f`. That will give a type error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best way to write this is:

```
f >>= g . head
```

or in a more verbose form:

```
f >>= (g . head)
```

so we basically perform an `fmap` on the value for `f` (we thus take the `head` of the values wrapped in the `IO` monad), and then we pass then to `g`, like:

```
(head <$> f) >>= g
```

is semantically the same.

But now what happens if we use `g <$> head <$> f`? Let us first analyze the types:

```
f :: IO [Int]
g :: Int -> IO ()
(<$>) :: Functor m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

(I used `m` here to avoid confusion with the `f` function)

The canonical form of this is:

```
((<$>) ((<$>) g head) f)
```

The second `(<$>)` takes a `g :: Int -> IO ()` and `head :: [c] -> c` as parameters, so that means that `a ~ Int`, `b ~ IO ()`, and `m ~ (->) [c]`. So the result is:

```
 (<$>) g head :: (->) [c] (IO ())
```

or less verbose:

```
g <$> head :: [c] -> IO ()
```

The first `(<$>)` function thus takes as parameters `g <$> head :: [c] -> IO ()`, and `IO [Int]`, so that means that `m ~ IO`, `a ~ [Int]`, `c ~ Int`, `b ~ IO ()`, and hence we obtain the type:

```
(<$>) (g <$> head) f :: IO (IO ())
```

We thus do not perform any real action: we `fmap` the `[Int]` list to an `IO` action (that is wrapped in the `IO`). You could see it as `return (print 1)`: you do not "evaluate" the `print 1`, but you `return` that wrapped in an `IO`.

You can of course "absorb" the outer `IO` here, and then use the inner `IO`, like:

```
evalIO :: IO (IO f) -> IO f
evalIO res = do
   f <- res
   f
```

or shorter:

```
evalIO :: IO (IO f) -> IO f
evalIO res = res >>= id
```

(this can be generalized to all sorts of `Monad`s, but this is irrelevant here).

The `evalIO` is also known as [**`join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join).

Comment: otherwise known as `join`. :)

Comment: @WillNess: yes, I was working on that at the moment of commenting ;)

Comment: I'd hesitate to call this an "unwrapping", since that implies you could unwrap a single `IO f` to get the `f`. I like to think of it as the outer `IO` "absorbing" the inner `IO`, leaving the `f` safely wrapped throughout the entire process.

Comment: @chepner: good point, do you think this is a better formulation?

Comment: Looks good to me. I don't know if there is any deeper subtlety that could say whether it's the inner or outer monad that "survives" the process, or if both are equally replaced by a new one :)

Comment: @chepner I think it is the outer 'shell' that stays on, so that the 'shell' is never 'off' and the 'inside' is never 'exposed' -- or equivalently, in a *bind*-combined computation the first computation's 'shell' is the *outer* one: `m a -> ...... -> m b`. Looking at the types in [this simple case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497671/haskell-graham-hutton-book-parsing-ch-8-what-does-parse-f-v-out-do-and/52508471#52508471) of Parser monad  is what convinced me so (look under ' *the types must "fit"* ').

Answer (score 4):

The first and second are exactly the same, because `<$>` is left-associative and `head` is a function, and `<$>` is `.` in the function monad. Then,

```
    g . head <$> f

    =  fmap (print . head) (return [1..5] :: IO [Int])
    =  do { x <- (return [1..5] :: IO [Int])
          ; return ( print (head x) ) }
    =  do { let x = [1..5] 
          ; return ( print (head x) ) } :: IO _whatever
    =       
            return ( print 1 )   :: IO (IO ())
```

We have one too many `return`s there. In fact,

```
    =  fmap (print . head) (return [1..5] :: IO [Int])
    =  return (print (head [1..5]))
    =  return (print 1)
```

is a shorter derivation.

The third one is

```
    (head <$> f) >>= g
  = (fmap head $ return [1..5]) >>= print
  = (return (head [1..5])) >>= print
  = (return 1) >>= print
```

which is obviously OK.