# Haskell: Graham Hutton Book Parsing (Ch-8): What does `parse (f v) out` do, and how does it do it?

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads

My question is about Graham Hutton's book [*Programming in Haskell 1st Ed*](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/book-old.html).

There is a parser created in section 8.4, and I am assuming anyone answering has the book or can see the link to slide 8 in the link above.

A basic parser called `item` is described as:

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]

item :: Parser Char

item = \inp -> case inp of
        [] -> []
        (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]
```

which is used with `do` to define another parser `p` (the `do` parser)

```
p :: Parser (Char, Char)

p = do x <- item
       item
       y <- item
       return (x,y)
```

the relevant *bind* definition is:

```
(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b

p >>= f = \inp -> case parse p inp of
                       [] -> []
                       [(v,out)] -> parse (f v) out
```

`return` is defined as:

```
return  :: a -> Parser a

return v = \inp -> [(v,inp)]
```

`parse` is defined as:

```
parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]

parse p inp = p inp
```

The program (the `do` parser) takes a string and selects the 1st and 3rd characters and  returns them in a tuple with the remainder of the string in a list, e.g., `"abcdef"` produces `[('a','c'), "def"]`.

I want to know how the 
        `(f v) out` 
in 
        `[(v,out)] -> parse (f v) out`
returns a parser which is then applied to `out`.

- `f` in the `do` parser is `item` and `item` taking a character `'c'` returns `[('c',[])]`?
- How can that be a parser and how can it take `out` as an argument?

Perhaps I am just not understanding what `(f v)` does.

- Also how does the `do` parser 'drop' the returned values each time to operate on the rest of the input string when `item` is called again?
- What is the object that works its way through the `do` parser, and how is it altered at each step, and by what means is it altered?

Answer (score 4):

`f v` produces a `Parser b` because `f` is a function of type `a -> Parser b` and `v` is a value of type `a`. So then you're calling `parse` with this `Parser b` and the string `out` as arguments.

> F in the 'do' parser is item

No, it's not. Let's consider a simplified (albeit now somewhat pointless) version of your parser:

```
p = do x <- item
       return x
```

This will desugar to:

```
p = item >>= \x -> return x
```

So the right operand of `>>=`, i.e. `f`, is `\x -> return x`, not `item`.

> Also how does the 'do' parser 'drop' the returned values each time to operate on the rest of the input string when item is called again? What is the object that works its way through the 'do' parser and how is it altered and each step and by what means is it altered?

When you apply a parser it returns a tuple containing the parsed value and a string representing the rest of the input. If you look at `item` for example, the second element of the tuple will be `xs` which is the tail of the input string (i.e. a string containing all characters of the input string except the first). This second part of the tuple will be what's fed as the new input to subsequent parsers (as per `[(v,out)] -> parse (f v) out`), so that way each successive parser will take as input the string that the previous parser produced as the second part of its output tuple (which will be a suffix of *its* input).

---

In response to your comments:

> When you write "p = item >>= \x -> return x", is that the equivalent of just the first line "p = do x <- item"?

No, it's equivalent to the entire `do`-block (i.e. `do {x <- item; return x}`). You can't translate `do`-blocks line-by-line like that. `do { x <- foo; rest }` is equivalent to `foo >>= \x -> do {rest}`, so you'll always have the rest of the `do`-block as part of the right operand of `>>=`.

> but not how that reduces to simply making 'out' available as the input for the next line. What is parse doing if the next line of the 'do' parser is a the item parser?

Let's walk through an example where we invoke `item` twice (this is like your `p`, but without the middle item). In the below I'll use `===` to denote that the expressions above and below the `===` are equivalent.

```
do x <- item
   y <- item
   return (x, y)
=== -- Desugaring do
item >>= \x -> item >>= \y -> return (x, y)
=== -- Inserting the definition of >>= for outer >>=
\inp -> case parse item inp of
             [] -> []
             [(v,out)] -> parse (item >>= \y -> return (v, y)) out
```

Now let's apply this to the input "ab":

```
case parse item "ab" of
     [] -> []
     [(v,out)] -> parse (item >>= \y -> return (v, y)) out
=== Insert defintiion of `parse`
case item "ab" of
     [] -> []
     [(v,out)] -> parse (item >>= \y -> return (v, y)) out
=== Insert definition of item
case ('a', "b") of
     [] -> []
     [(v,out)] -> parse (item >>= \y -> return (v, y)) out
===
parse (item >>= \y -> return ('a', y)) out
```

Now we can expand the second `>>=` the same we did the fist and eventually end up with `('a', 'b')`.

Comment: Thank you. When you write "p = item >>= \x -> return x", is that the equivalent of just the first line "p = do x <- item"? 

If so feeding f (= \x -> return x") into bind:

(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
p >>= f = \inp -> case parse p inp of
                       [ ] -> [ ]
                       [(v,out)] -> parse ((\x -> return x) v) out

I can sort of see how 'v' might be returned from that, but not how that reduces to simply making 'out' available as the input for the next line. What is parse doing if the next line of the 'do' parser is a the item parser?

Comment: Hutton says: "That is, the parser p >> = f fails if the application of the parser p to the input string fails, and otherwise applies the function f to the result value to give
a second parser, which is then applied to the output string to give the final
result. In this manner, the result value produced by the first parser is made
directly available for processing by the second." 
So bind applies two parsers with bind in each line of the 'do' parser - with item & a second invisible parser that outputs 'out' as input for item on the next line? I don't see how "parse (f v) out" can do that.

Comment: @JohnDawson I've expanded my answer in response to your comment. I hope that's cleared things up.

Comment: Thank you! I understand. Thank you for taking the time to explain. You have put me out of my misery and I can now continue with the book. I like the 'spareness' of Graham Hutton's book, but in section 8.4 there was just too much new on one or two pages fighting my expectations of how things should work.

Comment: item returns something of the form [(x,xs)]

p is defined as:

p = do x <- item
       item
       y <- item
       return (x,y)

how does x <- item match with just the x of (x,xs) and call it x ( or y )? 

Why, when the monad is 'unwrapped' and the underlying value taken out, doesn't the arrow <-  deliver the tuple (x,xs) and call that whole thing x (or y)  or fail - rather than just the first x from the tuple? @sepp2k

Comment: @JohnDawson Because that's how `>>=` is defined for `Parser`. If you look at the definition of `>>=` in the OP, it says `parse (f v) out` where `v` is the first element in the tuple and `out` is the second element. So `f` is called with the first item of the tuple, thus `x`, which is `f`'s parameter, will be that item.

Comment: Thank you. So the rule for identifying the "result value" is always to look at the definition of bind (p >>= f) and identify which value is applied directly to the function f and that will be the result value taken on by x in the do notation's "x <-"?  @sepp2k

Comment: @JohnDawson Yes. `x <- foo; ...` becomes `foo >>= \x -> ...` when `do`-notation is expanded, so `x` becomes whichever argument `>>=` uses as the argument to the function on its right (i.e. `f` in this case).

Answer (score 3):

The relevant advice is, *Don't panic* (meaning, don't rush it; or, take it slow), and, *Follow the types*.

First of all, `Parser`s

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]
```

*are* functions from `String` to lists of pairings of result values of type `a` and the leftover Strings (because `type` defines type synonyms, not new types like `data` or `newtype` do).

That *leftovers* string will be used as *input* for the *next* parsing step. That's the main thing about it here.

You are asking, *in*

```
p >>= f = \inp -> case (parse p inp) of
                       [] -> []
                       [(v,out)] -> parse (f v) out
```

> *how the `(f v)` in `[(v,out)] -> parse (f v) out` returns a parser which is then applied to `out`?*

The answer is, `f`'s *type* says that it does so:

```
(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b    -- or, the equivalent
(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> (String -> [(b,String)])
--       p              f                inp
```

We have `f :: a -> Parser b`, so that's just what it does: applied to a value of type `a` it returns a value of type `Parser b`. Or equivalently,

```
f    :: a       -> (String  -> [(b,String)])      -- so that
f (v :: a)      ::  String  -> [(b,String)]       -- and,
f (v :: a) (out ::  String) :: [(b,String)]
```

So whatever is the value that `parse p inp` *produces*, it must be what `f` is waiting for to proceed. The types must *"fit"*:

```
      p :: Parser a                     --   m  a
f       ::        a -> Parser b         --      a -> m  b
f <$> p :: Parser    ( Parser b )       --   m     ( m  b )
f =<< p :: Parser             b         --   m          b
```

or, equivalently,

```
p       :: String -> [(a,   String)]
--         inp         v    out
      f ::             a -> String   -> [(b, String)]
--                     v    out
p >>= f :: String                    -> [(b, String)]     -- a combined Parser
--         inp                            v2  out2
```

So this also answers your second question,

> *How can that be a parser and how can it take `out` as an argument?*

The real question is, what kind of `f` is it, that does such a thing? Where does it come from? And that's your fourth question.

And the answer is, your example in `do`-notation,

```
p :: Parser (Char, Char)

p = do x <- item
       _ <- item
       y <- item
       return (x,y)
```

by Monad laws is equivalent to the nested chain

```
p = do { x <- item
       ; do { _ <- item
            ; do { y <- item
                 ; return (x,y) }}}
```

which is a syntactic sugar for the nested chain of `Parser` *bind* applications,

```
p :: Parser (Char, Char) -- ~ String -> [((Char,Char), String)]

p = item >>= (\ x ->              -- item :: Parser Char ~ String -> [(Char,String)] 
               item >>= (\ _ ->                      -- x :: Char
                          item >>= (\ y ->           -- y :: Char
                                     return (x,y) )))
```

and it is *because* the functions are nested that the final `return` has access to *both* `y` *and* `x` there; and it is precisely the `Parser` *bind* that arranges for the output leftovers string to be used as input to the next parsing step:

```
p = item >>= f     -- :: String -> [((Char,Char), String)]
    where    
           { f x = item >>= f2
                    where { f2 _ = item >>= f3
                                    where { f3 y = return (x,y) }}}
```

i.e. (under the assumption that `inp` is a string of length two or longer),

```
parse p inp                            -- assume that `inp`'s 
  = (item >>= f) inp                   --  length is at least 2     NB.
  =
    let  [(v, left)] = item inp        -- by the def of >>=
    in                                
        (f v) left
  =
    let  [(v, left)] = item inp
    in
       let  x = v                      -- inline the definition of `f`
       in  (item >>= f2) left
  =
    let  [(v, left)] = item inp
    in let  x = v 
       in let  [(v2, left2)] = item left     -- by the def of >>=, again
          in (f2 v2) left2
  =
    ..........
  =
    let  [(x,left1)] = item inp        -- x <- item
         [(_,left2)] = item left1      -- _ <- item
         [(y,left3)] = item left2      -- y <- item
    in 
        [((x,y), left3)]
  =
    let   (x:left1)  = inp             -- inline the definition
          (_:left2)  = left1           -- of `item`
          (y:left3)  = left2
    in 
        [((x,y), left3)]
  =
    let   (x:_:y:left3) = inp
    in 
        [((x,y), left3)]
```

after few simplifications.

And this answers your third question.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar problems reading the syntax, because it's not what we are used to.

```
(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b

p >>= f = \inp -> case parse p inp of
                       [] -> []
                       [(v,out)] -> parse (f v) out
```

so for the question:

> I want to know how the  `(f v) out` in  `[(v,out)] -> parse (f v) out` returns a parser which is then applied to `out`.

It does because that's the signature of the 2nd arg (the **`f`**): `(>>=) :: Parser a ->` **`(a -> Parser b)`** `-> Parser b` .... **`f`** takes an **`a`** and produces a **`Parser b`** . a **`Parser b`** takes a **`String`** which is the **`out`** ... `(f v)` **`out`**.

But the output of this should not be mixed up with the output of the function we are writing: **`>>=`**

- We are outputting a parser ... `(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) ->`
  **`Parser b`** .
- The `Parser` we are outputting has the job of wrapping and chaining the first 2 args

A parser is a function that takes 1 arg. *This is constructed right after the first `=`* ... i.e. by returning an (anonymous) function: `p >>= f` **`= \inp -> ...`** so **`inp`** refers to the input string of the Parser we are building

so what is left is to define what that constructed function should do ... *NOTE: we are not implementing any of the input parsers just chaining them together* ... so the **output Parser function should**:

- apply the input parser (**`p`**) to the its input (`inp`): **`p`** `>>= f =` **`\inp`** `-> case` **`parse p inp`** `of`
- take the output of that parse `[(v, out)]` -- **`v`** is the result, **`out`** is what remains of the input
- apply the input function (`f` is **`(a -> Parser b)`**) to the parsed result (`v`)
- `(f v)` produces a **`Parser b`** (a function that takes 1 arg)
- so apply that output parser to the *remainder* of the input *after* the first parser (`out`)

For me the understanding lies in the use of destructuring and the realization that we are constructing a function that glues together the *execution* of other functions together simply considering their *interface*.

Hope that helps ... it helped me to write it :-)